# Fill a number of text boxes on an aspx page till generic list has been looped through

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, generic-list

What is a good way to fill a fixed number of text boxes on an aspx page till the generic list has been looped through and filled in all the empty text boxes that it can fill?

I now have the following but if there are less answers in the list then there are text boxes I get an outOfBoundException.

```
else if(!IsPostBack) {
    Groups group = new Groups();
    List<Answers> AnswerList = new List<Answers>();
    //Get the group since the session isn't null
    group = group.getGroupbyId(int.Parse(Session["group_Id"].ToString()));
    //Get the list of answers of the group
    AnswerList = Answers.retrieveAnswersBygroupIdandPageNumber(group.Group_Id, pageNumberLab);

    if (AnswerList.Count != 0) {
        while (TextAnswerNumber < AnswerList.Count) {
            ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

            foreach (Control control in cph.Controls) {
                if (control is Panel) {
                    Panel panel = (Panel)control;
                    foreach (Control controlInPanel in panel.Controls) {

                    //If the control is a textbox
                    if (controlInPanel is TextBox && controlInPanel.ID.Contains("txtAnswer")) {
                        //And if the control ID containst txtAnswer                                    
                        //IMPORTANT: If next programmer adds another textbox for an answer textbox the ID must be in the form txtMember*".
                        TextBox answerTextBox = (TextBox)controlInPanel;
                        // Check if the textbox is empty

                        if (answerTextBox.Text == "") {
                            //If it is, fill it with the answer that group filled in when it previously answered this question.
                            answerTextBox.Text = AnswerList[TextAnswerNumber].Answer;
                            answerTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
                            TextAnswerNumber++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
            }
```

Comment: I am not enamored with your code, but a real quick fix would be to add `&& (TextAnswerNumber < AnswerList.Count)` to the if(control isPanel)` check.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you aren't enamored by the code. I know it's not immediately relevant to the question but it might make it clearer. And thanks it works. I thought I tried that already and to no avail but it seems not.Edit: now I remember, I tried what you typed but instead of a regular if I used while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a foreach on the AnswerList

```
else if(!IsPostBack) { 
    Groups group = new Groups(); 
    List<Answers> AnswerList = new List<Answers>(); 
    //Get the group since the session isn't null 
    group = group.getGroupbyId(int.Parse(Session["group_Id"].ToString())); 
    //Get the list of answers of the group 
    AnswerList = Answers.retrieveAnswersBygroupIdandPageNumber(group.Group_Id, pageNumberLab); 

    if (AnswerList.Count != 0) { 
        foreach(Answer ans in AnswerList) { 
            ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"); 

            foreach (Control control in cph.Controls) { 
                if (control is Panel) { 
                    Panel panel = (Panel)control; 
                    foreach (Control controlInPanel in panel.Controls) { 

                    //If the control is a textbox 
                    if (controlInPanel is TextBox && controlInPanel.ID.Contains("txtAnswer")) { 
                        //And if the control ID containst txtAnswer                                     
                        //IMPORTANT: If next programmer adds another textbox for an answer textbox the ID must be in the form txtMember*". 
                        TextBox answerTextBox = (TextBox)controlInPanel; 
                        // Check if the textbox is empty 

                        if (answerTextBox.Text == "") { 
                            //If it is, fill it with the answer that group filled in when it previously answered this question. 
                            answerTextBox.Text = ans.Answer; 
                            answerTextBox.ReadOnly = true; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
            }
```

Comment: I'm fairly positive I tried that and it didn't work. But since Drake already provided me with a solution, I won't try this out right now just to check whether or not it doesn't work. Hope you understand, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @reaper_unique I prefer Chris's answer to my own, and hope you'll find some time to try it out.

Comment: But could you tell me why this is a better solution or why you prefer this over the one you provided yourself?
Also, I use the "counter" TextAnswerNumber further down my code to decide whether or not I need to write the data that is in the textboxes to my database. It's pointless to write the answers again and it would give me another problem, namely creating double entries in my database which in turn would provide problems when I want to fill the textboxes again when a user revisits this page.